# Skipping React Query's useQuery hook with useState on inital render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

So I have this Product component below that

1. Displays a list of components
2. Has a button that opens a modal to add components
3. Has an edit button in each row to open a modal and update that component.

I am using react-query for my api calls and while what I have at the moment is working, it feels janky and am hoping you guys can advise on a better way to put this together.

So this is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {  useGetProductsList, useGetProduct, useCreateProduct, prefetchProduct, usePutProduct, usePatchProduct } from '../api/ProductsApi';
import ModifyProducts from '../components/ModifyProducts'
import { compare } from 'fast-json-patch';

function Products(){
  const [productId, setProductId] = React.useState();
  const [product, setProduct] = React.useState();
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = React.useState(8);
  const productsQuery = useGetProductsList(page, pageSize);
  const productQuery = useGetProduct(productId)
  const [addModalIsOpen, setAddModalIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [editModalIsOpen, setEditModalIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [createProduct, createProductInfo] = useCreateProduct();
  const [putProduct, putProductInfo] = usePutProduct();
  const [patchProduct, patchProductInfo] = usePatchProduct();

  const headerStyles = "px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider";
  const onPut = async (values) => {
    putProduct(values)
  }

  const onPatch = async (values) => {
    let patchDoc = compare(product, values)
    patchProduct({productId: values.productId, patchDoc})
  }

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let current = true;
    if(productId){
      if(current)
        setProduct(productQuery.data)
    }

    return () => {
      current = false
      setProductId(null)
    }
  },[productId, productQuery.data])

  // React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  //   let current = true;
  //   if(productId){
  //     axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/${productId}`)
  //       .then((res) => {
  //         if(current)
  //           setProduct(res.data)
  //       })
  //   }

  //   return () => {
  //     current = false
  //   }
  // },[productId])

  function openEditModal(newProductId) {
    setProductId(newProductId)
    setEditModalIsOpen(true)
    putProductInfo.reset();
  }
  
  function openAddModal() {
    setAddModalIsOpen(true)
    createProductInfo.reset();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="">
        <div className="pb-5 border-b border-gray-200 space-y-3 sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between sm:space-x-4 sm:space-y-0">
          <h2 className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">
            Products
          </h2>
          <div>
            <span className="shadow-sm rounded-md">
              <button onClick={() => openAddModal()} type="button" className="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-indigo focus:border-indigo-700 active:bg-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                Add new product
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        { (productsQuery.isSuccess || productsQuery.isLoading) && (
          <div className="pt-5 flex flex-col">
            <div className="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
              <div className="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div className="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-t-lg">
                  <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th className={headerStyles}>Name</th>
                        <th className={headerStyles}>Style</th>
                        <th className="px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50"></th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                      {productsQuery.products.map((product) => (
                        <tr>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            {product.name}
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">
                          {product.style}
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-right text-sm leading-5 font-medium">
                            <button onClick={() => openEditModal(product.productId)} onMouseEnter={() => prefetchProduct(product.productId)} className="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit</button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  
                  <nav className="bg-white px-4 py-3 flex items-center justify-between border-t border-gray-200 sm:px-6">
                    <div className="hidden sm:block">
                      <p className="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 space-x-1">
                        Showing
                        <span className="px-1 font-medium">{productsQuery.products.length === 0 ? 0 : (page * productsQuery.currentPageSize)-productsQuery.currentPageSize + 1}</span>
                        to
                        <span className="pr-1 font-medium">{productsQuery.products.length === 0 ? 0 : ((page * productsQuery.currentPageSize)-productsQuery.currentPageSize + 1) + productsQuery.products.length - 1}</span>
                        of
                        <span className="pr-1 font-medium">{productsQuery.totalCount}</span>
                        results
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex-1 flex justify-between sm:justify-end">                      
                      <PageButtons page={page} setPage={setPage} hasPreviousPage={productsQuery.hasPrevious} hasNextPage={productsQuery.hasNext}></PageButtons>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          )
        }
      </div>

      
      {(
        <>
          <ModifyProducts
            isOpen={addModalIsOpen}
            setIsOpen={setAddModalIsOpen}
            onSubmit={createProduct}
            clearOnSubmit
            createProductInfo
            submitText={
              createProductInfo.isLoading
                ? 'Saving...'
                : createProductInfo.isError
                ? 'Error!'
                : createProductInfo.isSuccess
                ? 'Saved!'
                : 'Add Product'
            }
          />
            
          {/* you can use either onPut or onPatch depending on if you want to update with patch or put */}
          <ModifyProducts
            isOpen={editModalIsOpen}
            setIsOpen={setEditModalIsOpen}
            initialValues={product}
            onSubmit={onPatch}
            editProductInfo = {patchProductInfo}
            submitText={
              patchProductInfo.isLoading
                ? 'Saving...'
                : patchProductInfo.isError
                ? 'Error!'
                : patchProductInfo.isSuccess
                ? 'Saved!'
                : 'Save Product'
            }
            />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}


function PageButtons(props) {
  return ( 
    <>
      { props.hasPreviousPage && (
        <button onClick={ () => props.setPage(props.page - 1) } className="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-700 bg-white hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
          Previous
        </button>
      )}
      { props.hasNextPage && (
        <button onClick={ () => props.setPage(props.page + 1) } className="ml-3 relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-700 bg-white hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
          Next
        </button>
      )}
    </>
   );
}

export default Products;
```

and here's the react query hook i am importing in:

```
// get individual
const fetchProduct = (productId) => {if(productId) axios.get(`${apiURL}/${productId}`).then((res) => res.data)}
function useGetProduct(productId) {
  const results = useQuery(
    ['product', { productId }],
    fetchProduct(productId),
    {
      // enabled: false
      // initialData: () =>
      //   queryCache.getQueryData('products')?.find((d) => d.productId === productId),
      // staleTime: 2000,
    })

    return { ...results, products: results.data ?? loadingProducts }
}
```

You'll notice the important part at the beginning:

```
const [productId, setProductId] = React.useState();
  const [product, setProduct] = React.useState();
  const productQuery = useGetProduct(productId)

  const headerStyles = "px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider";

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let current = true;
    if(productId){
      if(current)
        setProduct(productQuery.data)
    }

    return () => {
      current = false
      setProductId()
    }
  },[productId, productQuery.data])

  // React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  //   let current = true;
  //   if(productId){
  //     axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/${productId}`)
  //       .then((res) => {
  //         if(current)
  //           setProduct(res.data)
  //       })
  //   }

  //   return () => {
  //     current = false
  //   }
  // },[productId])
```

The point here is to have a product id in state and, when I click on a row in the table to edit a record, it sets the product id and fetches the data from the api. This works with the commented out code, but doesn't use react-query. Wanting the power of react query, I worked on refactoring it to  use what I have above. It does work. but it feels wrong.

The biggest issue I ran into was when I first set this up, my useQuery would always have a call on the initial render with the undefined productId and fail. As you might have noticed, I tried adding `enabled: false` to my useQuery, so I could call it manually, but it wasn't working for some reason. Maybe you guys have some other ideas.

Regardless, appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use useEffect for useGetProductsList and useGetProduct to be called just once when component is mounted, and you can bind one useEffect in productId just in case that changes

And i would prefer call the functions seperately instead of React.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
// ...

function Products(){
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(8);
  const [addModalIsOpen, setAddModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [editModalIsOpen, setEditModalIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // Will call once the component is mounted
    const productsQuery = useGetProductsList(page, pageSize);
    const [createProduct, createProductInfo] = useCreateProduct();
    const [putProduct, putProductInfo] = usePutProduct();
    const [patchProduct, patchProductInfo] = usePatchProduct();
  },[]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // Will call when productId is changed
    const productQuery = useGetProduct(productId)
  },[productId]);

  // ...
```

Ofc, just my opinion